# How to Moq DataLakeServiceClient in .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, azure-data-lake

I have a .NET Core application, in which I have a method that will connect to Azure Data Lake:

```cs
public DataLakeServiceClient GetDataLakeServiceClient(string StorageAccount)
{
    string clientId = _authenticationConfig.ClientId.Substring(6, _authenticationConfig.ClientId.Length - 6);
    TokenCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        _authenticationConfig.TenantId, clientId, _authenticationConfig.ClientSecret, new TokenCredentialOptions());

    string dfsUri = "https://" + StorageAccount + ".dfs.core.windows.net";

    DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), credential);
    return dataLakeServiceClient;
}
```

This is how I use it:

```cs
DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = _azureDataFactoryRepository.GetDataLakeServiceClient(_azureStorageClient.AzureStorageAccount02Value);
```

I try to write a unit test case where I try to moq the `GetDataLakeServiceClient`:

```cs
_azureDataFactoryRepository.Setup(x => x.GetDataLakeServiceClient(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns();
```

In the above code it should return `DataLakeServiceClient` but I am struggling how can I do this.

I do not see any method `IDataLakeServiceClient` also.

Can someone help me to setup above method?

Comment: @Niranjaongodbole Why don't you simply return with a new `DataLakeServiceClient`, like this: `.Returns(new DataLakeServiceClient())`? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakeserviceclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Files_DataLake_DataLakeServiceClient__ctor) says that its parameterless constructor is designed for mocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataLakeServiceClient` is an `abstract` class so you can just mock this and inject this mock into the higher level mock. So you want something like:

```
var moqDataLakeServiceClient = new Mock<DataLakeServiceClient>();
_azureDataFactoryRepository
             .Setup(x => x.GetDataLakeServiceClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(moqDataLakeServiceClient.Object);
```

I'm not sure what mocking client you're using so the above is using Moq.